# get fixed number of items from array list c#

Tags: c#

I would like to create a list variable of items from another list. So lets say I have a list of 100 items I would like to pull items 25 - 35 and put them inside of another list. is there a way of doing this without calling a big for statement and pulling out the element one by one and putting that into a list.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can use [`.Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) and [`.Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) from `System.Linq` ....

Like this:

```
var result = myList.Skip(24).Take(10);
```

and if you need use [ToList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) on the result to get another list

Answer (score 2):

For a `List<T>`, you can use the [`GetRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21k0e39c.aspx) Method.

> Creates a shallow copy of a range of elements in the source List(Of
>   T).

Do note that the second argument represents the *count* of elements in the range, not the end-index of the range.

Since you mention `ArrayList`, I should point out that while it too has a `GetRange`, method, the type is considered essentially legacy since .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Use both Take and Skip

```
var newList = oldList.Skip(25).Take(10);
```

Comment: that will skip one element to much